# Add link to parent site on non-publishing site

Tags: navigation

So I am creating three site templates, a site collection root template, a next level template and a third level template. What I need, is to be able to add a link to the different levels that is dynamic when I reuse the template.

So if you are on the 2nd level, you'll have a link to the root. If you're on the third, you'll have a link to root and 2nd.

Is this possible in a non-publishing site? I could hard code, but then I'd have to change it on ever new subsite which is not going to happen.

Thanks.